# In an Azure logic app using oracle get rows how to I query a table with a $ in the table name

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a logic app that finds all the err$ tables in an oracle database (err$_table_name are the default names of the rejected row tables for the log errors option). The problem I am stuck on is that when I use the oracle get rows action, the dollar sign in the table name is causing a json error.

**Error message - BadRequest. Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON.**

In the "Inputs" sections the table name is correct, in this case the table name is **"CHEETAH.ERR$_ALL_D_MARKET_HIER"**

Under the raw inputs though I see this and I can see the $ was switched to %2524

```
{
    "method": "get",
    "path": "/datasets/default/tables/CHEETAH.ERR%2524_ALL_D_MARKET_HIER/items",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/oracle-3"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code view of the the get rows action:

```
"method": "get", 
"path": "/datasets/default/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(concat(variables('Owner'), '.', variables('Table') )))}/items"
```

I get the this json error if I enter in the table name or if I pass in the table name via a variable.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to get this to work. The only workaround I can think of is to use a stored procedure to create views without the $ in them.

Tried the suggestion of the slash .  It changed the error at least.

Looking at below it took the single slash I added and replaced it with two slashes.

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The specified item 'CHEETAH.ERR\\$_ALL_D_PROD_HIER' is not found.\r\n     inner exception: The specified item 'CHEETAH.ERR\\$_ALL_D_PROD_HIER' is not found.\r\nclientRequestId: b9038635-4007-48f5-aebd-ce94e1faf90a",
  "error": {
    "message": "The specified item 'CHEETAH.ERR\\$_ALL_D_PROD_HIER' is not found.\r\n     inner exception: The specified item 'CHEETAH.ERR\\$_ALL_D_PROD_HIER' is not found."
  },
  "source": "oracle-cc.azconn-cc.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Comment: This is the code view of the get rows 
"method": "get",
                            "path": "/datasets/default/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(concat(variables('Owner'), '.', variables('Table') )))}/items"

Comment: Hi Rambis, perhaps update your question rather than adding the comment. It will make it easier for those reviewing your question.

Comment: Have you tried `CHEETAH.ERR\$_ALL_D_MARKET_HIER` to escape `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and it had nothing to do with the $ in the table name.  It was the data being returned in one of the columns.

The problem column was of data type "UROWID"